Wrong bounding box dimensions for a Mesh Line node since Blender 4.0
Wondering why some 3d abstract patterns I did some months ago https://skfb.ly/oQuX7 (on my previous old computer where I used to stick to Blender 3.3) appear different in Blender 4.2, I managed to isolate the problem and it turns out that since version 4.0, Blender gives wrong bounding box dimensions to a mesh line generated by geometry nodes https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/primitives/mesh_line.html (as long as the Geometry Nodes modifier is not applied)
Correct bounding box in Blender 3.3.21:

Wrong bounding box in Blender 4.2.2:


Both the bounding box optionally displayed in the 3D Viewport https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/display.html#bpy-types-object-display-bounds-type, and the rectangular cuboid generated if we add a "Bounding Box" node, appear in Blender 4+ larger that they should be: actually they show the dimensions that would be correct if the Mesh Line node "Count" option was set to one unit higher (in my example file it would be 5 vertices instead of 4)
I wonder if there is some justification to that or if it is simply a bug that should be solved in the future. For the time being a possible workaround is to add a "Split Edge" and "Merge by Distance" nodes after the "Mesh Line" node.

It does look like a bug. Instead of spliting the edges and merging the points, you can place a set position node with no values. It should be less slow.


Thanks for this tip and also for having quickly reported the bug yourself https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/129388
